# Python - Streaming audio to Google Cloud silently failling

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to stream audio in a Int16 array format from Flask server to Google Cloud Speech Api. For some reason it's silently failing, probably it has something to do with how I'm using the stream generator or sending the data in a wrong forma

Google Cloud Documentation says that stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data. Not very explicit, I tried building a generator.

Why I'm not getting response from google cloud?

This is the main code

```
@ws.route('/websocket')
def audio(ws):
    total_msg = ""
    sample_rate = 16000
    while True:
        def generator():
            msg = ws.receive()                  
            if msg is not None:
                audio_as_int_array = numpy.frombuffer(msg, 'i2')
                yield(audio_as_int_array)
        stream = [generator()]
        requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
                for chunk in stream)
        language_code = 'en-US'  # a BCP-47 language tag
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate,
            language_code=language_code)
        streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        config=config,
        interim_results=True)
```

Comment: I love the title!

Comment: Why? :) @ReblochonMasque

Comment: LOL - even better if it was unintended! :D

Comment: Any hint? @ReblochonMasque

Comment: Opps `audio_as_int_array = numpy.frombuffer(msg, 'i2')` I'm sorry, but you don't know the size, and you can't handle blocks with no head/end. If you need to log in, check your information.You cannot analyze an undefined block.

Comment: @dsgdfg Interested in tutoring for $? Really need some help with this

Comment: Check if the sound is coming. >> Copy the volume to a specific block size. >> Set Audio channel. >>Analyze sound . Which of these did you do or not? First try on the your computer, then run it on the server.

Comment: @Juanvulcano **If you love money, people use that addiction.**

Comment: @dsgdfg When trying to print audio_as_int_array I got different arrays according to the audio I was streaming. I suppose that every msg have a different size? How do I add head/end know the size of buff?